# How Risky is Paribus?

Tags: email

Paribus (https://paribus.co/) is a service that automatically gets money back for you if there's a price drop on a product you purchased.

It seems to work by monitoring your email, to which you must give it read / write access to.  Yup, that's the risky part.

They say impressive-sounding things on their FAQ page (https://paribus.co/faq) like "tokens" and "TLS".  And they do offer a perhaps slightly less-risky suggestion to create a separate email account just for online purchases.

Their service is free - they take 25% of any savings they can get for you.

But I wonder if it's worth the obvious risk (and maybe less obvious problems) of allowing a 3rd party service into my email.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think you basically answered your own question. The risk of having your email being read is simply too great to get a few bucks back on your overpriced products.

Comment: It is not the 25% that they want, it is the gaining and selling of your id combined with buying habits.That is a gold mine for ad companies.

Comment: Emails are free. Create another one just for Paribus and have fun. And saying that one will gain more than you is silly. Let them earn something and you something too. You will be profiled, as you always are on every link you click.

Comment: Additionally, to giving access to your email, you have to give them login info to certain accounts, like Amazon, which now exposes your stored credit card information on Amazon. That password is a key to your credit. NO WAY!

Comment: Amazon doesn't expose full credit card information -- that would be a break of PCI compliance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at it from a security point, I wouldn't recommend it. You're giving someone else the rights of your e-mail, they are basically you from that point.

And just like @AstroDan said they are gathering information about your buying habits. It makes it easier for you, but someone else is making much more money of it.

Comment: Divulging passwords or allowing others access to your account is also against the TOS of many services.